# tkinter changing a button's state weirdly acting

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I'm a beginner programmer and trying to learn `tkinter` module. I'm trying to change my button's state when it's clicked. I'm able to change it by using: `my_button.config(state="active")`
When I check it by printing: `print(f"After: {my_button.cget('state')}")`

it says its active. I mean everything happens to be normal so far.

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.minsize(width=500, height=500)


def change_button_state():
    print(f"Before if statement: {my_button.cget('state')}")
    if my_button.cget("state") == "normal":
        print(f"Before: {my_button.cget('state')}")
        my_button.config(state="active")
        print(f"After: {my_button.cget('state')}")
    else:
        print(f"Before: {my_button.cget('state')}")
        my_button.config(state="normal")
        print(f"After: {my_button.cget('state')}")


my_button = Button(text="Something", command=change_button_state)
my_button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

The problem occurs when I clicked the button again. Let me show you the outcome of clicking the button twice before I explain further.

```
Before if statement: normal
Before: normal
After: active

Before if statement: normal
Before: normal
After: active
```

I mean how can second `"Before if statement"` be `"normal"`? Didn't I just changed it to active? I'm really lost at this point. If you can help me I would be glad.

Comment: Do you want all three" normal"?

Comment: Tkinter will set the state of the button to be "active" whenever the mouse is over (enters) it and returns to "normal" when the mouse leaves. The only was to stop this from changing would be to override the "Enter" event for the button.